# input value cant be found in memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, angular-ngmodel

Im currently trying to build a date input field using a datepicker then grab the value that it gets and place it into an object in my controller. The specific part of the HTML is below:

```
 <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">
   <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-M-yyyy"data-provide="datepicker">
      <input readonly type="text" id="OpenDate" class="form-control" style="background-color: white;" placeholder="dd-Mon-yyyy" ng-model="advancedSearch.openDate">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
           </span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Currently I can see the date that i pick in the input box on the page, however neither the model value or any js query of the input fields value have a value. here's how i'm checking them:

```
$('#OpenDate').change ( function () {
    console.log('1) ' + 'test');
    console.log('2) ' +$('#OpenDate').value);
    console.log('3) ' +$scope.advancedSearch.openDate);
});
```

all i get is:

1) test 
2) undefined 
3)

I'm unsure why this is happening because (from what i understand) the ng-model field should grab the text that's being shown.

Comment: What `datepicker` plugin are you using ? and please try `$('#OpenDate').val()` !

Comment: Two comments: First, your input field is **readonly**; second, you may consider settings its type as `date` instead of text.

Comment: using <code> $('#OpenDate').val() </code> worked for test 2, but the angular stuff still isn't working. Also I'm unsure what Datepicker I'm using (someone else wrote the code before me),